# What constraints (if any) are there on network interface names on linux

Tags: linux, networking, linux-kernel, network-interface, iproute

In https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24932172/what-length-can-a-network-interface-name-have, it was asked how long a network interface name could be (apparently 16 bytes). However, the answers to that question do not seem to link to any information about what other constraints there are on the name, such as:

- character set (e.g. with `ip link` I'm able to have `;rm` and `-f` as valid names, but it doesn't seem to be able to parse names with spaces (though that could simply be an artefact of its argument parser, and not actually a protection against problematic values)).
- minimum length (1 byte names are valid)
- encoding (creating `α` displays `__` in my terminal, and it cannot be deleted by the name `α`)

Is there any documentation on what can an interface be called, and at what layer it is enforced (e.g. in the kernel, iproute2, libc)?

Context: writing a CLI commmand which accepts interface names which will get stored in a database, I'd like to determine how much filtering of bad names I can do without causing issues with weirdly named (though probably not hostile) interfaces.

Comment: There are probably not many restrictions on the interface name, but many scripts and programs will break if the name is strange, so some names may be allowed but not actually work correctly.   Also, if you use the correct database interface with placeholders instead of injection, and correct quoting in html pages, it should not be necessary to filter the names.

Comment: Regardless of what the system accepts, given we know how much trouble the complete freedom of filenames gives to all shell programmers (witness half the questions here), I think you couldn't be blamed if you stricter limits than the kernel does. Heck, one could probably just restrict the device names to the portable filename character set (`a-zA-Z0-9._-`)... (well, unless someone wants to name the devices in another language than English, but I'm not English either and have never seen any use in forcing another language in such a low-level matter...)

Comment: @ilkkachu While I'd like to filter out as large a set as possible, some of the system is implementing existing and widely used interfaces, so for compatibility I don't want to rule out too much.

Comment: [PoC||GTFO 0x16:08](https://www.alchemistowl.org/pocorgtfo/pocorgtfo16.pdf) demonstrates some interesting conflicts between interface names and the `iptables` command.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The interface name should not look like `ethNUM`, `wlanNUM` or `usbNUM`.

Those names are used by the kernel, and you will run into trouble if you try to rename an interface to something like that. I know that from my own experience (of trying to keep two interfaces stably named `eth0` and `eth1`, irrespective of the order in which the kernel was initializing them).

See [this](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/16665#issuecomment-669160229).

---

As to froggy characters, the kernel's interface (`ioctl(SIOCSIFNAME)` ... `dev_change_name()` ... [`dev_valid_name()`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/net/core/dev.c#L1048)) will reject any interface name which is the empty string, `.` or `..`, contains any `/`, `:` or spaces (`[\t\n\v\f\r \xa0]`), or is longer than **15** (not 16) bytes:

```
bool dev_valid_name(const char *name)
{
        if (*name == '\0')
                return false;
        if (strnlen(name, IFNAMSIZ) == IFNAMSIZ)
                return false;
        if (!strcmp(name, ".") || !strcmp(name, ".."))
                return false;

        while (*name) {
                if (*name == '/' || *name == ':' || isspace(*name))
                        return false;
                name++;
        }
        return true;
}
```

Other control characters like `\x1b` (ESC), invisible/bidi marks or any kind of binary garbage work fine. You can try for instance: `ip link add dev $'\e[1;41;33m' type bridge` ;-)

Comment: Really useful! I'm still slightly weirded out why `α` wasn't saved correctly though, but that may be some additional logic in iproute2 (or my terminal, but I haven't had unicode issues before...).